# Problem using 1:M -> M:1 in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've set up a relational db using MSSQL and I'm trying to use the Entity Framework to talk to it, but I'm having some issues. (This is my first EF project).

I'm able to insert data in both the `Machines` table and the `Contacts` table using:

```cs
_db.AddToMachines(new Machine { MachineModelId = 0, Owner = "Test", SerialNo = "34242341" });
_db.SaveChanges();
```

But how can I add Contacts to the Machine?

[image: Small segment of the database]

[image: EF]

Comment: How does the EDM model look like?

Comment: @Enrico Campidoglio: Updated the question with a new picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Machines` entity should have a navigation property called `Contacts` and vice versa. Just add the objects to these properties.
Example:

```
var machine = new Machine { MachineModelId = 0, 
                            Owner = "Test", SerialNo = "34242341" };
var contact = new Contact { ... };
machine.Contacts.Add(contact);

_db.AddToMachines(machine);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

This should insert a new entry in the `Machines` table, a new entry in the `Contacts` table and a new entry in the `MachineContacts` table referencing the new entries in the two other tables.

Comment: It may be that the EDM model includes an entity for the `MappingContacts` mapping table with a M:1 relationship to both the `Machine` and `Contact` entities. In that case a new `MachineContact` object must be added to both the `Machine.MachineContacts` and `Contact.MachineContacts` navigation properties.

Comment: @Enrico: That is very unlikely, because pure mapping tables like the one shown by the OP are normally not created as entities, because they are not necessary in the OOP world.

Comment: @Sindre: What means you are "not able to add anything to it"? What happens?

Comment: @Daniel Agreed, but is that what Visual Studio does by default when generating an EDM model from a database schema?